# Determine if iFrame element exists as a child element within wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

With the following snippet:

```
let iframe = videoWrapper;
console.log(iframe);
```

I get the following return:
[image]

Within `video-player`, I have the following child elements:
[image]

What is the best way to determine if `<iframe>` exists within that parent wrapper and check all levels of child elements?

`<iframe>` can be one or two levels within parent element, so it all depends.

Bonus points if I can determine if `data-src` exists within the iFrame.

I can't seem to track it at all - I have tried the following items:

```
let iframe = videoWrapper.parents().eq(2).find('iframe');  
let iframe = videoWrapper.contents().find('iframe');  
let iframe = videoWrapper.find('iframe');  
let iframe = videoWrapper.find('iframe').length;
```

Nothing seems to have worked, all help will be appreciated!

Comment: Bonus points for you if you explain "_Nothing seems to have worked_" - please provide error conditions or logs or explain what leads you to believe it doesn't work.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, as in... I haven't been able to target the iFrame element or I probably wouldn't have posted this question? - Those are all the attempts to attempt to grab the `<iframe>` element.

Comment: So no errors exist? Where is the content of the iframe coming from?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, technically, no - But I also didn't properly target it, so I guess I called that an error :\

Comment: I edited my comment to include the question about the origin of the content of the iframe - where does the iframe content come from?

Comment: When calling `let iframe = videoWrapper.parents().eq(2).find('iframe');` I am able to target the `<iframe>` if it's literally the first child element of the parent, but if it has the `<div style="">` as in the photo, then I'm not able to target it.

Comment: I was hoping that I could do `videoWrapper.children().find('iframe');` where it checks all the child elements, but that also didn't return an iFrame result.

Comment: please produce a [example] that demonstrates this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand what you asked for correctly.

```
// check if exists
if ($('div.video-player iframe').length > 0) {
    alert('frame exists');
    
}

// for finding child elements
let iframeMain = $("div.video-player iframe").contents().find('#something deeper than iframe main tag');
// then just go deeper
let iframe2ndLevelDeeper = $(iframeMain).contents().find('#something even more deeper inside iframe');

// check for data-src
let dataSrc = $('').attr('data-src');

const $iframe = document.querySelector(`iframe`);

$iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
    if (dataSrc !== '') {
       console.log("loaded and exists");
    } else {}
    
});
```